# Python3: How to store information from short script in a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a script that searches Google for Lil Wayne articles, and then -- for each article -- returns title, summary, url, and keywords.

But I would really like to make a CSV file that had TITLE, SUMMARY, URL, KEYWORDS as columns and then stored the relevant information for each article in each row.

```
from newspaper import Article 
import google 

#Search Setup
for url in google.search('Lil Wayne', num=10, stop=3, pause=0):
    article = Article(url)      
    article.download() 
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()     


    #Print the parsed output of each article
    print(u'TITLE: ' + str(article.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
    print(u'SUMMARY: ' + str(article.summary.encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
    print(u'URL: ' + str(article.url))
    print(u'KEYWORDS: ' + str(article.keywords)) 
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Is this actually Python 3? Python 3 wouldn't need the `u` prefix on text string literals, and `str(article.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))` would behave funny (`str` would return the `repr` of the `bytes` object `encode` returns).

Comment: In any event, I strongly suggest you actually check the [`csv` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html); this is mostly boilerplate, and the examples there should get you started.

Comment: Hi, 

Yeah I originally wrote this in python 2 and I am pretty sure I messed up the decoding. 

I eventually get the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 170: invalid start byte`

Do you know what's up with that?

Comment: Without a traceback, I can't tell you specifically. If the goal is to write `csv` that might contain non-ASCII text though, stop trying to do this in Python 2, and use Python 3 instead. You won't need to call `decode` at all, the `csv` module will handle the full Unicode range without a problem (you can store the original text, instead of dropping data on the floor like `decode` with `errorhandler` `"ignore"` does). Worst case scenario, you'd need to explicitly pass `encoding='utf-8'` or the like to the `open` function, so it uses an encoding that can represent the whole Unicode range.

Comment: Basically, if you need to handle non-ASCII text, Python 3 is better, and if it's non-ASCII CSV, the Py2 `csv` module is a royal pain, and writing portable code is going to be a headache; target Py3 and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this in your code:

```
from newspaper import Article 
import google 

with open('output_file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    lil_wayne_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    #Search Setup
    for url in google.search('Lil Wayne', num=10, stop=3, pause=0):
        article = Article(url)      
        article.download() 
        article.parse()
        article.nlp()
        lil_wayne_writer.writerow(
            [
                str(article.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                str(article.summary.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),
                str(article.url),
                str(article.keywords),
            ]
        )
```

This basically opens a csv writer, then writes each row as you find an article. There is more info about csv writers [in the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

You might need to edit it a little to work properly in your environment.

If you would like to write the headers into your CSV file, simply add a single call to something like this:

```
lil_wayne_writer.writerow(['TITLE', 'SUMMARY', 'URL', 'KEYWORDS'])
```

Comment: Assuming this is really Py3, you'd want to `decode` back to `str` (or pass a second argument to the `str` constructor); otherwise, you get the `repr` of the `bytes` object. So `str(article.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore')),` would become either `str(article.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore'), 'ascii'),` or `article.title.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'),`. Also, you need to open the output file with `open('output_file.csv', 'w', newline='')` not `'wb'` without `newline`; the Py3 `csv` module is `str` based, not bytes based.

Comment: Thanks @ShadowRanger - I'll add those options to my research list to improve my Python3 chops :).